# PC crashing after cpu detached from cooling source

Tags: cpu, cpu-cooler, thermal-paste, processor-socket

I detached CPU cooler from the processor, took the processor out for examination & installed it back. However,  I didn’t apply a thermal paste in between, and left the old dry substance that was between cpu & a cooling medium as is. Now my PC crashes randomly, even sometimes before or during boot screen comes on, to complete stop, as if it was breefly unplugged. Could a lack of proper thermal paste application cause this phenomena?

Thanx!

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Yes. It can also cause *much* worse problems depending on what CPU you have.

Comment: "Now my PC crashes randomly" - Because you have improperly reinstalled the CPU.  You need to replace the thermal paste.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of thermal paste is to ensure optimal transfer of heat between the CPU package and the heat sink. Because modern processors can generate lots of heat in such a small space, they need all the help they can get to remove that heat. Because the surfaces of the integrated heat spreader and heatsink are not perfect, thermal paste is used to ensure optimal thermal contact by bridging microscopic gaps in these surfaces.

On modern hardware, it's actually quite hard to cause damage to a processor due to overheating. There are thermal sensors built into nearly all modern processors designed to limit clock frequency and eventually shut down altogether if the detected temperature is too high.

Standard procedure is to replace the thermal paste. It does dry out over time, and should be replaced every two to three years for optimal performance. In some cases, you may be able to get by for a long time if you don't remove the cooler. (My father's desktop ran for an entire decade on the stock heat sink and thermal paste.) But as soon as you detach the HSF assembly or waterblock, the thermal contact is broken, and any dried-up thermal paste needs to be replaced.

For general use, I'd say [Noctua NT-H1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CQU14A) is probably the best choice. For intensive usage, including overclocking, [Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011F7W3LU) will give you the best possible performance from a conventional thermal paste, but is also much more expensive.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  Try to find a non-conductive thermal compound if you are new to this; consequently over-application of conductive thermal compound can cause short circuits and instability as well.

Comment: There are metal-containing pastes like Arctic Silver which are overall not conductive.  However, you should put on the minimum needed (less than half a CC) from a precision tube nozzle, and not be squirting the paste all over.  The paste should not overflow the CPU socket when applying the pressure plate.